# Im a beginner and I cannot bake my normals

Tags: uv, normals, baking, normal-map

I spend some times trying to bake this normal using extrusion, cage, lower poly 'low poly' mesh, tried to redo UV unwraping, resize UV meshes or even using 8k normal map resolution.
It always comes out messed up : some faces are not baking, resolution is messed up or corners are messed up.

It would be really appreciated if someone more experienced just took a look and told me what am I doing wrong.
I submit the told meshes so you can try.

file link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hte5S0I0RwMG8h0eUp685rq7fK4V6jbU/view?usp=sharing

original high poly mesh
[image: original high poly mesh]
normal baked with extrusion at 0.002 on low poly mesh
[image: normal baked with extrusion at 0.002 on low poly mesh]

Comment: it works fine for me but I don't see all the details you show in your second image. Apply the scale of your objects, in the Bake panel activate Selected to Active, choose an Extrusion value of 0.1. Create a 32-Bit Float Image in your Image Texture, lower down the Normal map value down to 1, bake

Comment: try changing 'srgb' to 'linear' in the image panel, found in the shader nodes editor. for some reason its always set to srgb by default